# Asp.Net - AspPageHandler does not fire with button

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

(using .NET Core 3.1)

I have a handler which works, however I can't call it from a `<button/>`. From an `<a/>` it works (but this will try to refresh my page and it's not what I want).

```
//GETS TO HANDLER
<a class="btn btn-info" asp-page-handler="SearchProductionRecords">
    <i class="fas fa-file-excel mr-2"></i> Export Excel
</a>

//NEVER GETS TO HANDLER
<span class="input-group-append">
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="SearchProductionRecords" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> </button>
</span>
```

```
//HANDLER
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSearchProductionRecordsAsync()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button submit is associated with a form submit. Therefore, put the button inside a form method=post and it should work.

Kind Regards,

Maheshvara

Comment: Hmm, that did it. I could swear I didn't actually needed to specify the `method="post"` (I think, but not sure, I have used it before without it), but it was that.  I was playing with the method names, with the `viewImport` files all over, checking my routes, etc. Thank you for your help.